# Visual studio 2015 can't compile even Hello World program

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I tried to run this simple Hello world example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But VS returned the following error:

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(2): fatal error C1083: cannot open file corecrt.h: No such file or directory

After some googling I found possible solution. It was said to add the following values to project -> properties -> AdditionalIncludeDirectories and AdditionalLibraries:

```
$(UniversalCRT_IncludePath)
$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86)
```

When I did that nothing happend. VS returned the same error.

How do I correct that?

Comment: are you including #include "stdafx.h" as is needed for VS ?

Comment: Did you create a Win32 Console Application?

Comment: No, I just created an empty project and added .cpp file to source files directory.

Comment: Project templates contain different settings (include directories for example), use the one appropriate for you. Empty Project is likely to require more fiddling to get it to compile.

Comment: @egorik Was it a Win32 empty project? Maybe you have randomly created a non-C++ one?

Comment: When you create a new project you need click in visual c++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Console Application.  Try that.

Comment: Yes, I chose win32 console application and then chose empty project in the settings page.

Comment: @user That's not needed.

Comment: Did you try running a repair on visual studio? The toolchain might be broken.

Comment: Can you goto Solution Explorer -> Project -> Properties -> VC++ Directories and let us know what the content there is?

Comment: @J. Murray http://imgur.com/a/72czl

Comment: @egorik - Your include path looks correct when compared with a working project I have open in VS.  If you Edit the Include Directories, you can see the actual paths for your build by using the"MACROS" button on the lower right.  This might help you spot a missing path.

Comment: @J. Murray I probably find out what is wrong. My operating system is Windows 10 while the target platform of my program was set to 8.1. And I don't have Windows 10 SDK installed on my PC. Maybe that's the essence? If so, do I have to install Win 10 SDK or is there another solution?

Comment: @J. Murray you're right. I changed some paths via MACROS button and now  my program is compiled fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a number of different factors - it is dependent on how you created the project.

Regardless, you can determine if your build paths are correct by checking the following:

(Solution Explorer) : Click on your project, and then select the Project Properties.  From there, check the VC++ Directories page, and look at your Include Directories.

[image]
  It should contain $(VC_IncludePath); and $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);.  If it contains these, edit the Include Directories, and select the MACRO button so you can see the actual paths in use for your build tools.

[image]

Chances are one of them is incorrect.

[image]